# alternative to opengrok

Tags: opengrok

I am using for an alternative to OpenGrok. I can't configure it properly. What I want is to browse to the code, like I would be in Visual Studio. I'd like to have a menu with a minimum option of Go To Definition, find references etc. How can that be achieved ?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to have a look at the [Woboq Code Browser](http://woboq.com/codebrowser.html).

It works like a compile step and dynamically analyzes the code and how symbols are linked to each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you have problems configuring it on Windows?

OpenGrok works best through a web-server.  You might find it easier to rent some cheap VPS box, and configure OpenGrok remotely on such server (instead of trying to configure it locally on a Windows box), and then use your web-browser to access the remotely-running OpenGrok instance through the web-interface.

I've once tried using OpenGrok locally on a Windows machine, and even though it worked, I was not happy that the non-web version didn't have any syntax highlighting, and was overall just way too awkward to be of any real use.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Text-Sherlock](http://cbess.blogspot.com/2011/10/text-sherlock-opengrok-alternative.html). And [the github project](https://github.com/cbess/text-sherlock). It can use either Whoosh or Xapian as its backend.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Codatlas. It has features such as jump-to-definition and cross-reference and poly-glot support such as C/C++, Java, Python, Scala etc.